# Can I use my valid Schengen visa in old passport after i have new passport with new name?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I am a Russian citizen. I have Schengen visa type C valid till 01/03/2020 and I am going to change my name and I will keep my surname as it is.

Can I travel with my new passport with new name and old passport which has a valid Schengen visa in the new year to Europe?

Comment: @Daniil I would not close this.  The other question does not involve a name change.